# I want to retrieve a part of the data in Firebase. How do i achieve this?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Fragment Code

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

    usersList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    noUsersText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);

    mProgressDialogue = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialogue.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialogue.show();

    String url = "https://messageplus-cd647.firebaseio.com/.json";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            doOnSuccess(s);
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("" + volleyError);
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    rQueue.add(request);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

**doOnSuccess** Method

```
public void doOnSuccess(String s){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

        Iterator i = obj.keys();
        String key = "";

        while(i.hasNext()){
            key = i.next().toString();

            if(!key.equals(UserDetails.phonenumber)) {
                al.add(key);
            }

            totalUsers++;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(totalUsers <=1){
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , al));
    }

    mProgressDialogue.dismiss();
}
```

The problem is, In the URL mentioned above, the data present is Unique Id of users. Inside Unique id there are 4 fields - **Name, Number, Email, Gender**. I want to retrieve only the names of the users How do i achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question. It's easier for everyone to understand your problem and make sure their answer works. Therefore by a bit of work by you you can spare multiple other people the same, tedious work.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: d child is the user ids of all users. inside the user ids contains their info like name email etc. i want to retrieve only name which is a child of user id